# Find out specific group Oralce

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data in the PK of a table SUBJECT_GRP

```
GRP_ID    SUBJECT
1         Comp Science
2         Comp Science
2         Math
2         Physics
3         Chemistry
3         Math
3         Physics
```

I am using below query in my logic

```
SELECT RELATIVE_GROUPS.GRP_ID
FROM (SELECT GRP_ID, count(1) ALL_CNT 
      FROM SUBJECT_GRP GROUP BY GRP_ID) ALL_GROUPS,
     (SELECT GRP_ID, count(1) RELATIVE_CNT
      FROM SUBJECT_GRP 
      WHERE ((INSTR(:sqli_subject, '@' || RTRIM(SUBJECT) || '@', 1, 1) > 0 ))
      GROUP BY GRP_ID) RELATIVE_GROUPS
WHERE ALL_GROUPS.GRP_ID = RELATIVE_GROUPS.GRP_ID
  AND ALL_CNT = RELATIVE_CNT

For :sqli_subject = '@Comp Science@Math@Physics@'
```

I want only group 1 and group 2 as output. Does someone have efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want  group 1 and group 2?

Comment: As per my inputs :sqli_subject only 1 & 2 should be retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is working fine, an alternative could be use of `count` in analytic version, this way table is hit only once:

```
select distinct grp_id 
  from (
    select grp_id, subject, count(1) over (partition by grp_id) cnt1,  
           count(case when instr('@Comp Science@Math@Physics@', 
                           '@' || rtrim(subject) || '@', 1, 1) > 0 
                      then 1 end) over (partition by grp_id) cnt2
      from subject_grp )
  where cnt1 = cnt2
```

Test data:

```
create table subject_grp(grp_id number(3), subject varchar2(20));
insert into subject_grp values (1, 'Comp Science' );
insert into subject_grp values (2, 'Comp Science' );
insert into subject_grp values (2, 'Math' );
insert into subject_grp values (2, 'Physics' );
insert into subject_grp values (3, 'Chemistry' );
insert into subject_grp values (3, 'Math' );
insert into subject_grp values (3, 'Physics' );
```

Comment: I did not understand your query but giving what I want, Only one hit. Thanks:)